# Any free way to disable copying text in .pdf?

Tags: copy-protection, acrobat

I'm providing a free sample page that will be downloaded from my website that is in .pdf format. I want to prevent users from selecting and copying the text content of that document. How can I do this for free?

Comment: What's the point? If they can read the text, they could just transcribe it manually or print+OCR.

Comment: True - people are lazy sometimes though. I'd just like the security measure there (even as easily crackable as it is).

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  People who have a need to copy it will just get around it anyway.

Comment: Another way is to convert text to curves with ghostscript: `gs -o output.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite input.pdf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Adobe Acrobat, you can create passwords to protect pdf files. But others can still use some pdf tools to crack passwords. Look at this article.
http://www.anypdftools.com/blog/2009/05/12/create-and-crack-pdf-password.html#261

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Good looking out!

Comment: link is not working properly anymore, could you put the most important info to the answer and make it valuable?

Comment: Please mind that the protection must be enforced *by the application* that views the PDF. The document still contains copyable text (and processable by other means) and there is quite a lot of viewer applications that either do not have this “functionality” implemented or allow user to bypass this protection. Also, for some other applications (`pdftotext`, to name one), such protection is not meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

Convert the text to image before fetching it as a PDF.