# How do PDFs prevent copying?

Tags: pdf

According to this:
[Any free way to disable copying text in .pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611089/any-free-way-to-disable-copying-text-in-pdf)

> With Adobe Acrobat, you can create passwords to protect pdf files. But others can still use some pdf tools to crack passwords

This to me implies that without cracking the password, you cannot copy any text from a protected document. How does this work from a technical perspective?

Is the text-copy prevention detection simply a feature of Adobe Reader, in which case someone could create a pdf reader that does not enforce this, or is there something more to it?

Comment: Yes, it would be somewhere in the reader.  And yes, they can be circumvented http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-circumvent-pdf-editing-security/

Comment: It's not worth doing even if you could do it in a fool proof way. Even if you disable copying text which disables screen capture, anyone can take a photo of the screen and use OCR.

Comment: The original pdf permissions have been modeled in a cooperative manner, i. e. all pdf processing software has to implement this permission scheme. This was more or less ok as long as more or less all pdf processing software was provided by Adobe but those times are long gone by now.